# Filtering in tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtag, tweepy

I am new to `tweepy` and have encountered a problem. I want to download tweets with special hashtags. But it seems

```
stream.filter(track = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'])
```

looks for these words in tweet and not in hashtags of the tweet. How can I filter on hashtags?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You find the tags in the status object. It is there you have to make the comparison with the ones you are looking for.

example:

```
for hashtag in status.entities['hashtags']:
    print(hashtag['text'])
```

example here: http://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-tweepy-twitter-for-python/

Comment: But won't this just do something after the filtering has occurred, hence you need to use dbernard's answer?

Comment: This is not accomplishing any filtering until after you've received the tweets, which defeats the purpose.  See @dbernard's answer for the correct way to filter on a #hashtag.

Answer (score 12):

You can actually filter tweets based on your special hashtag.

```
stream.filter(track=['#MySpecialHashtag', '#AlsoThisHashtag'])
```

This will pick up only tweets that contain the hashtags you provide as part of the tweet text and save you from arbitrarily collecting tweets and checking if the hashtag field has your hashtag in it.

Comment: question: will this be case sensitive?

Comment: @AkshayKadidal The Twitter API docs don't specify - I would assume they are case sensitive, but you'd have to sanity check me there.

docs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/statuses-filter

Comment: as on 12  July 2019, it is not case sensitive. I tested it against my account