# Tweepy- retrieve the most popular two hashtags

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, spark-streaming, tweepy

I'm a beginner in Spark Streaming.
I am test some code that is functional, but I want to do something else with it. I want to retrieve only the most popular two hashtags in my account.

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['python'])
```

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering in tweepy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497731/filtering-in-tweepy). This does not address the "top two hashtags on my account" issue, but I have a feeling that asking users to write this much on top of boilerplate is excessive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is the following (full example [here](https://github.com/giordano91/twitter_scripts/blob/master/get_hashtags_from_user.py)):

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    hashtags_dict = {}

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name='<your_screen_name',count=200)

    for tweet in tweets:
        hashtags = tweet.entities.get('hashtags')
        for hashtag in hashtags:
            if hashtag['text'] in hashtags_dict.keys():
                hashtags_dict[hashtag['text']] += 1
            else:
                hashtags_dict[hashtag['text']] = 1

    print(sorted(hashtags_dict, key=hashtags_dict.get, reverse=True)[:2])
```

The new part that I have added to your script gets 200 tweets from your account and loops each tweet for get the relative hashtags.
Each hashtag will be added as key in a dict (hashtags_dict) and as value I put how many times the hashtag has been used.

At the end, I get the two keys in the dict with the max value, that corresponds to the most popular two hashtags in your account.

You can get only 200 tweets at the same time, this is the maximum allowed count. If you want get all tweets look at this [script](https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496)

Let me know.